# How can I send a Location header relative to the router that is sending the response?

Tags: express

I have an `express` app that links up a `router` on some path.  One of the routes in that `router`, let's call it `commands`, can create a document.  After that document is created, I want to send back a `201` status and a `Location` header with the location of the created document which can be accessed somewhere in the `commands` routing.

Is there a way to send back the location of this created document relative to the `router` that sends the response?  I'd prefer not to hardcode the location.

### Server.js

```js
app.use("/commands", require("./routes/commands"));
```

### commands.js

```js
// Have a create route to create documents somewhere in the commands router
router.get("/create", function (req, res) {
    // Figure out what id were going to give our new document
    var documentIdToCreate = nextDocumentId;

    // Create the new document
    documents[documentIdToCreate] = new Document();

    // Increment the document id
    nextDocumentId = nextDocumentId + 1;

    // Set "Created" status
    res.status(201);

    /*
    Set the location of the created document.  I would think
    that express would have some mechanism for the router to
    locate itself either by doing some sort of path.resolve
    type method.
    */
    res.location(util.format("/%s", documentIdToCreate));

    // End the response
    res.send();
});
```

In the end, I want to be able to send back the location by doing something like `res.location(router.relativeContextPath() + "/" + someDocumentId);` as apposed to having to send back `res.location("/commands/" + someDocumentId);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `router.mountpath` ([docs here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.mountpath)) and/or `req.baseUrl` ([docs here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.baseUrl)) will do the trick.